# How to sort objects by future time in Swift?

Tags: swift, sorting, datetime

I have an array of objects with a `time` property that I would like to sort in a special way. I'd like to sort them so the object that has a future time first, then times get sorted behind it, then cycles back to past items. Here's what I have so far:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var name: String = ""
    var time: Double = Double(0)
}

var currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
var myArr: [MyStruct] = []
myArr.append(MyStruct(name: "Abc", time: currentTime - 3)) // Past
myArr.append(MyStruct(name: "Def", time: currentTime - 5)) // Past
myArr.append(MyStruct(name: "Ghi", time: currentTime - 1)) // Past
myArr.append(MyStruct(name: "Jkl", time: currentTime + 3)) // Future
myArr.append(MyStruct(name: "Mno", time: currentTime + 2)) // Future

var mySorted = myArr.sorted { $0.time < $1.time }

mySorted // Outputs structs in this order: Def, Abc, Ghi, Mno, Jkl
```

I can't figure out what to do in the sort predicate to sort by the closest future times first. In other words, I'd like to show the next object that's coming up based on the current time. So the above should sort as: `Mno, Jkl, Ghi, Abc, Def`. I've been racking my brain on this and hoping someone can see an algorithm for this?

Comment: You just have the < in the wrong direction. Change it to >

Comment: Ah you are right, but still I think I need to pop the closest future item and inset it back at the top. Thx!

Comment: What you could do is just split them up into 2 arrays using filter() one arr in past and one arr in future and then sort them and put them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a more functional style you can use

```
let mySorted2 = 
    myArr.filter{ $0.time > currentTime }.sorted{ $0.time < $1.time } +
    myArr.filter{ $0.time <= currentTime }.sorted{ $0.time > $1.time }
```

I think this code is more readable because the code matches your requirements more closely. Take all future dates and sort them in ascending order, then append all past dates sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be that difficult... The comparison is different if they are both in the past, both in the future or one on each side.

This code should work:

```
var mySorted = myArr.sorted { (a: MyStruct, b: MyStruct) in
    var c = currentTime
    if a.time > c && b.time > c {
        // both in the future
        return a.time < b.time
    }
    else if a.time < c && b.time < c {
        // both in the past
        return a.time > b.time
    }
    else if a.time > c {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```